# Access to nested object in JSON ,select the right value in a dropdownlist (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, rest, server, dropdown

I am a beginner in AngularJS. I used the $resource service to get a specific object of type person based on its **id** from the server in order to update this object.

**Resource service:**

```
moduleName.factory('Person', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/application/person/:id', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET' , params: {id: '@id'}},
  });
});
```

The object that I received and it displayed in my browser using the {{}} is:

```
      {
  "id": "560cf96ee85532035928889e",
  "firstName": "Christiane",
  "gender": "Male",
  "flight": {
    "id": null,
    "arrivalDate": "2015-01-05 11:30",
    "arrivalAirport": {
      "name": "Frankfurt"
    },
    "stopovers": []
  }
}
```

In this form I have a dropdownlist that contains the Airport list, I expect that the value of the arrivalAirport will be selected in this dropdown list, but no value was selected, I try to set the selected value of this dropdown list in the AngularJs controller of this view.Before setting the value of this object I try to access to their value by this code inside the controller.

```
moduleName.controller('PersonDetailController',function ($scope, $routeParams, Person,$location) {
                $scope.person = Person.show({id: $routeParams.id});
                console.log($scope.person.flight.arrivalAirport);
        });
```

when I want to get the value of the object **flight.arrivalAirport** nested in  **person** object I got this error.

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrivalAirport' of undefined**

How can I display the right value selected in the dropdown list and how can I access to the other object like **stopovers** array in order to update their values?

**Thank you.**

Comment: There is no property named `departureAirport` in your object, so why should it be defined?

Comment: I made a typo in the attribute name , thank you

Comment: what's the output of console.log($scope.person)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call console.log Person's data hasn't been retrieved yet. You should do something like this:

```
$scope.person = Person.show({id: $routeParams.id}, function(person) {
    console.log(person.flight.arrivalAirport);
});
```

In general, any code working on data received asynchronously can't be put right after the call because it's very unlikely that data has been retrieved at that point, you should use callbacks and promises.

Your view should update automatically, and you said it does, at least for the part showing the json. In order to make the dropdown update you should bind its values to a property inside $scope.person

If the dropdown doesn't update then there must be some other error and you might need to post the dropdown's code too.
If you want to manually update the dropdown's list instead then you need to put the relevant code inside the callback (the function i added to "person.show" in the code above) in order to make it work

Comment: Thank you ,your answer helped me to find a solution

Comment: Glad i've been of help